# Como parsear correctamente la respuesta de una solicitud ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

Estoy llenando un `datatable` pero quisiera medir la longitud del `array` que me devuelve la consulta. Ademas de esto elegir qué elementos del `array` quiero mostrar y cuales no.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente

```
var data2 = JSON.stringify({
                usuario: $('#h_user').val(),
                estado: $('#MainContent_estado option:selected').text(),
                buscarPor: $('#MainContent_buscarPor option:selected').text(),
                fecha_ini: $('#MainContent_fechaIni').val(),
                fecha_fin: $('#MainContent_fechaFin').val()
            })

         $('#datatable').DataTable({
                        'dom': 'Bfrtip',
                        'buttons': [
                            {
                                extend: 'excelHtml5', className: 'btn btn-primary', exportOptions: {
                                    columns: ':visible'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                extend: 'pdfHtml5', className: 'btn btn-primary', exportOptions: {
                                    columns: ':visible'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                extend: 'colvis', className: 'btn btn-primary', text: 'Columnas Visibles'
                            }
                            //'colvis'
                        ],
                        "columnDefs": [ {
                            "targets": -1,
                            "visible": false
                        } ],
                        "autoWidth": true,
                        "ajax": {                
                            "url": "http://vr.zom.com/extranete/WSo/Servicioss.svc/buscaReferes",
                            "type": "POST",
                            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            "data": function (d) {

                                return data2


                            },


                            "error": function (jqXmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                               // alert("Datos Incorrectos"); //#coment
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

y si funciona se llena el datatable con los datos pero ahora quiero filtrar que dobjetos del array mostrar

Comment: La función definida en `"data"` no funcionará, el parámetro es `d` y devuelves `data2`. Asumo que `d` es la respuesta recibida, así que puedes mirar la longitud con `d.length`, por ejemplo

Comment: Hola Pablo lozano! me da undefined si quiero medir la longitud de d
gracias por el comentario bro!

Comment: `"data"` es la informacion que le vas a pasar a la url, no la que esta retorna.  Necesitas pasarle algo a tu url o no?

Comment: si , le doy return data2 porque data2 trae el valor de las cajas de texto , ya edite la pregunta para darles mas contexto
gracias por tomarte el tiempo de contestar

Comment: @emanuelle estás integrando el ajax en tu tabla, no necesitas declarar la data. Solo asegurate que los resultados de tu ajax los regrese en una propiedad con el nombre de data.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que buscas es la propiedad dataSrc.  Se usa asi:

```
"ajax": {                
            "url": "http://ver.moz.com.mx/extranet/WS/Servicios.svc/buscaRefer",
            "type": "POST",
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "data": function (d) {
                        return data2
            },
            "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
                         console.log(json.data.length);
                         return json.data;
            }
        }
```

Comment: eso funciono ! Gracias